# How do I merge all the cases into One

Tags: shell

How can I merge the following two case scripts?

**Script 1**

```
#!/bin/bash
Ver=0
n="192.168.1.20:/backup/b1"
o1="192.168.1.20:/backup/b2"    
User="1234"
echo "n Latrest version"    
echo "o1 Previous version n-1"
echo "o2 Previous version n-2"
echo -n "Which version you want to backup [n or p]? "
read Ver    
case "$Ver" in    
(n|o1|o2) scp $User@${!n} . ;;    
(*) echo "UNKNOWN USER"    
esac
```

Above script is not working properly error

```
cannot stat `1234@': No such file or directory
```

**Script 2**

```
User=0    
av="34567"    
ma="4568"    
im="5678"    
mi="12345"    
pr="23456"    
echo "Please select av ma ji im pr"    
echo -n "First 2 initial of your Name eg: [av ma ji im pr]? "    
read User    
case "$User" in    
(av|ma|pr|mi|im) scp ${!User}@$n . ;;    
(*) echo "UNKNOWN USER"    
esac
```

Comment: You mix up variables `$n` and `$Ver`, and you don't specify `$o2`.

Comment: Ooohhhhh Yes!!!. But still i need to make both of them run togather i want to Merg it

Comment: This question is lacking a good title. With the current title, no-one will ever be able to find your question and benefit from it. But if others can't benefit from your question, it's not a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a mix up between variables `$n` and `$Ver`, and the value of `$o2` was not specified.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "want to download [yes no]? "
read response
[ "$response" = "yes" ] || exit

n="192.168.1.20:/backup/b1"
o1="192.168.1.20:/backup/b2"
o2="192.168.1.20:/backup/b3"
echo "n Latest version"
echo "o1 Previous version n-1"
echo "o2 Previous version n-2"
echo -n "Which version do you want to backup [n o1 o2]? "
read opt
case "$opt" in
    n|o1|o2)
        server="${!opt}"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "INVALID OPTION" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

av="34567"
ma="4568"
im="5678"
mi="12345"
pr="23456"
echo -n "Enter your initials [av ma im mi pr]: "
read opt
case "$opt" in
    av|ma|im|mi|pr)
        user="${!opt}"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "UNKNOWN USER" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

scp "${user}@${server}" .
```

Comment: I want to add this below line before executing this above script

Comment: want to down load yes or no? if the user says yes, then this above script should run

Comment: `echo 'want to download [yes no]?'; read response; [ "$response" = "yes" ] || exit; <rest of script>`. Next time ask a separate question.

Comment: i am still unable to understand how can i put this line before the script and run it.

Comment: i tried to created new ticket but that was giving an error code improper

Comment: I've put it into my answer. Does it work now?